# Найти похожий объект в Dataframe и заменить пустое значение

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, scipy

Хочу заменить пропущенные значения в Dataframe путем нахождения самого похожего наблюдения, и заменить пропуск его значением.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import random
from scipy.spatial import distance

a = [0,1] * 10
b = [1,0] * 10
df = pd.DataFrame({'S': np.arange(100,500,20),
                  'A': np.arange(20,80,3),
                  'V': np.arange(60,120,3),
                  'N': np.arange(986,45876,2300),
                  'B': a,
                  'B1': b},
                 index=[np.arange(0,20)])

#Мой Dataframe имеет следующий вид:
df.head()
     S   A  V    N    B B1
0   100 20  60  986   0 1
1   120 23  63  3286  1 0
2   140 26  66  5586  0 1
3   160 29  69  7886  1 0
4   180 32  72  10186 0 1

#Создам произвольный вектор который будет похож на 1 наблюдение
d = [78,18,55,980,0,1]

#Посчитаю дистанцию между d и первым наблюдением
dist = round(distance.euclidean(d,df.iloc[0],2))
#Ответ равен = 33
#Для убеждения посчитал разницу между другими элементами, всё работает корректно

#Создам пропущенное значение во втором элементе признака S
df['S'].iloc[1] = np.nan
df.head()

     S    A  V  N     B B1
0   100.0 20 60 986   0 1
1   NaN   23 63 3286  1 0
2   140.0 26 66 5586  0 1
3   160.0 29 69 7886  1 0
4   180.0 32 72 10186 0 1

#Создам отдельный Dataframe где удалены все пропуски 
df_drop = df.dropna()
```

**Проблема**: 
Вот на это мести у меня ничего дальше не получается. По логике должно быть следующее: Так как у нас пропуск в признаке `S` следовательно вектор нашего пропущенного наблюдения будет `23 63   3286  1 0`(все остальные значения кроме пропущенного). Далее нам необходимо сравнить данный вектор со всеми векторами `df_drop`(так как там нет пропусков) за исключением признака `S`. Тот вектор к которому будет самое близкое расстояние и будет самым похожим объектом. Нужно во первых получить что именно за наблюдение стало самым близким, во - вторых взять значение признака `S` у ближайшего соседа и заменить им пропуск нашего исходного наблюдения. Я пробывал по разному реализовать данную идею, перербирал циклами в основном, но постоянно натыкаюсь на ту или иную ошибку . Уверен что решение моей задачи существует). Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: сделайте столбец из дистанций и df.newColumn.idxmin() даст вам индекс строки с минимальным значением

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пропробуйте воспользоваться [fancyimpute](https://github.com/iskandr/fancyimpute):

```
from fancyimpute import *   #   pip install fancyimpute


def impute(df, imputer, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(imputer, SoftImpute):
        X = BiScaler().fit_transform(df)
    else:
        X = df
    res = pd.DataFrame(
        imputer(**kwargs).fit_transform(X),
        columns=df.columns,
        index=df.index)
    return res.astype(df.dtypes)

res = {}

res["KNN"] = impute(df, KNN, k=3)
res["SI"] = impute(df, SoftImpute)
res["II"] = impute(df, IterativeImputer)
res["MF"] = impute(df, MatrixFactorization)
res["IS"] = impute(df, IterativeSVD)


for alg, r in res.items():
    print(f"Imputed value:\t{r.iat[1, 0]:.3f}, used [{alg}] algorithm:")
```

---

результат:

```
Imputed value:  124.444, used [KNN] algorithm:
Imputed value:  37.583, used [SI] algorithm:
Imputed value:  120.000, used [II] algorithm:
Imputed value:  327.293, used [MF] algorithm:
Imputed value:  64.348, used [IS] algorithm:
```

Comment: Спасибо. Почитаю про данную библиотеку. Для начала я хотел посчитать расстояние по разным метрикам. Например если вектор бинарный в таком случае расстояние Хеминга, если нет, то можно Евклидово. Вообщем хочу посмотреть что из этого получится. Спасибо вам за предоставление решения!