# Элемент Dataframe отображается некорректно

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

После искусственного создания пропуска с типом `np.nan` весь Dataframe после этой строки выдает по индексу непонятные значения которых нет в Dataframe

```
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance

#Создаю Датафрейм
a = [0,1] * 10
b = [1,0] * 10

df = pd.DataFrame({'S': np.arange(100,500,20),
                  'A': np.arange(20,80,3),
                  'V': np.arange(60,120,3),
                  'N': np.arange(986,45876,2300),
                  'B': a,
                  'B_1': b},
                 index=[np.arange(0,20)])

df.head()

     S   A   V  N     B B_1
0   100 20  60  986   0 1
1   120 23  63  3286  1 0
2   140 26  66  5586  0 1
3   160 29  69  7886  1 0
4   180 32  72  10186 0 1

#Создаю пропуск в данных
df['S'].iloc[1] = np.nan
df.head()

     S    A   V   N     B   B_1
0   100.0 20  60  986   0   1
1   NaN   23. 63  3286  1   0 
2   140.0 26. 66  5586  0   1
3   160.0 29  69  7886  1   0
4   180.0 32. 72  10186 0   1
#Пропуск создался корректно
```

**Проблема:** Теперь все данные в таблице которые от 2-ой строки и ниже выводятся следующим образом:
`df.iloc[1].values`  выводит: `array([      nan, 2.300e+01, 6.300e+01, 3.286e+03, 1.000e+00, 0.000e+00])` мне не понято откуда взялись эти значения. Причем если я обращусь по индексу , в таком случае все будет корректно. `df.iloc[1].values[4]` выводит `1`  что соответствует действительности.
Если я сделаю вывод по срезу до предпоследнего элемента `df.iloc[1].values[0:4]` вывод также соответствует реальным данным `array([  nan,   23.,   63., 3286.])` . Но если я сделаю срез от начала до конца `df.iloc[1].values[0:5]` в таком случае я опять получаю несуществующие данные `array([      nan, 2.300e+01, 6.300e+01, 3.286e+03, 1.000e+00])` .Данная проблема актуальна для всех строк от той в которой я создал пропущенное значение `np.nan`. С первой строкой всё в порядке , можете проверить. Если вас не затруднит покажите пожалуйста  как мне нужно было делать чтобы получить реальные значения из таблице.

Comment: а для чего вы используете атрибут `.values` вообще?

Comment: @MaxU Вообщем идея заключается в следующем: Пропущенные значения заменить не классическим способом mean median mode , а найти самое похожее наблюдение из датафрейма и взять это значение у него. Например у наблюдения есть пропуск в признаке Возраст, мы ищем самый похожий на него другой объект и берем от туда возраст и заменяем пропуск. Для этого мне нужно сравнивать расстояние по векторам. Для этого я и использую values чтобы получить вектор , и далее этот вектор сравнить с каждым вектором датафрейма и получить самый похожий объект.: Подробнее: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1095884/325850

Comment: Для данной задачи измененный во `float64` тип данных не является помехой  Экспоненциальное __представление__ данных не меняет сами данные ;)

Comment: Да, спасибо вам за помощь!

Answer (score 3):

Pandas использует "под капотом" для работами с числами Numpy и его типы.
Когда вы берёте `values` от Pandas Series, вы получаете на выход массив Numpy (кажется, кроме того случая, когда вы работаете со строками).
Так получилось, что `NaN` в Numpy имеет тип `numpy.float64`, "целочисленного" `NaN` пока ещё не сделали, хотя и обещали в будущих версиях Pandas.
Соответственно, вы получаете на выходе массив чисел с плавающей точкой, которые на печати обычно представляются в том виде, который вы и наблюдаете. Это те же самые целые числа, которые вы поместили в DataFrame, просто они преобразовались в числа с плавающей точкой функцией `values`.
Массивы Numpy в отличие от списков Python не могут иметь разные типы для разных элементов массива, тип массива "повышается" до такого, в который "влезут" все элементы, которые мы пытаемся в него поместить, в данном случае это numpy.float64.

Comment: Спасибо, понял. А какой выход можно найти?

Comment: А это смотря что вы собственно хотите. Это те же самые данные, только в другом представлении.

Comment: Вообщем идея заключается в следующем: Пропущенные значения заменить не классическим способом mean median mode , а найти самое похожее наблюдение из датафрейма и взять это значение у него. Например у наблюдения есть пропуск в признаке Возраст, мы ищем самый похожий на него другой объект и берем от туда возраст и заменяем пропуск. Для этого мне нужно сравнивать расстояние по векторам. Для этого я и использую values чтобы получить вектор , и далее этот вектор сравнить с каждым вектором датафрейма и получить самый похожий объект.: Подробнее: ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1095884/325850

Comment: Не будет же считаться ошибкой если я например оставлю такое же представление данных?

Comment: Повторюсь. Это практически те же самые числа, только на печати они выглядят по-другому. Если ваш метод поиска похожих спокойно принимает на вход и int и float, то проблем никаких не будет.

Comment: Да, понял. Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 3):

Причина в том что в Numpy матрицах для всех элементов матрицы используется один единственный тип данных. Кроме того целочисленные типы данных в Numpy не умеют хранить значение `NaN` и как только хотя бы одному элементу массива присваивается значение `NaN`, то тип данных автоматически повышается до `float64`. `Pandas DataFrame` - это коллекция независимых друг от друга `Series`, которые по сути являются именоваными и индексированными одномерными Numpy матрицами - векторами. Поэтому когда вы присваиваете одной ячейке DataFrame значение `NaN` - тип данных меняется только в одном столбце, содержащем ячейку.

Пример для наглядности:

создадим целочисленный DF:

```
In [19]: d = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2], 'b':[3,4]})

In [20]: d
Out[20]:
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4

In [21]: d.dtypes
Out[21]:
a    int64
b    int64         # <---  NOTE !
dtype: object

In [22]: d.values
Out[22]:
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 4]], dtype=int64)
#  NOTE ------------> ^^^^^
```

теперь присвоим одной ячейке значение `NaN` и посмотрим что получится:

```
In [23]: d.loc[1, 'b'] = np.nan

In [24]: d
Out[24]:
   a    b
0  1  3.0
1  2  NaN

In [25]: d.dtypes
Out[25]:
a      int64
b    float64      # <---  NOTE !
dtype: object

In [26]: d.values
Out[26]:
array([[ 1.,  3.],
       [ 2., nan]])

In [27]: d.to_numpy()
Out[27]:
array([[ 1.,  3.],
       [ 2., nan]])

In [28]: d.values.dtype
Out[28]: dtype('float64')
#  NOTE ------> ^^^^^^^
```

---

**UPDATE:** по поводу различного представления одного и того же числа в Python:

практически любое число можно выразить или приблизить с точностью до маленького эпсилон при помощи экспоненциальной записи:

```
In [35]: 3286 - 3.286e3
Out[35]: 0.0

In [36]: 0.0123 - 1.23e-2
Out[36]: 0.0
```

---

```
In [37]: 0.1 + 0.2
Out[37]: 0.30000000000000004

In [38]: 0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3
Out[38]: 5.551115123125783e-17  # <--- это значение стремящееся к нулю
```

`5.55 в степени (-17)`, или `1 / 5.55^17` равно нулю с точностью до 17-го знака после десятичной точки