# Python pandas проверить значение на None

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance

#Создаю Dataframe
a = [0,1] * 10
b = [1,0] * 10
df = pd.DataFrame({'S': np.arange(100,500,20),
                  'A': np.arange(20,80,3),
                  'V': np.arange(60,120,3),
                  'N': np.arange(986,45876,2300),
                  'B': a,
                  'B_1': b},
                 index=[np.arange(0,20)])

#Создаю пропущенное значение в таблице через np.nan
df['S'].iloc[1] = np.nan
df.head()

      S    A    V   N      B    B_1
0   100.0 20    60  986    0    1
1   nan   23    63  3286.  1    0
2   140.0 26    66  5586.  0    1
3   160.0 29    69  7886.  1    0
4   180.0 32    72  10186. 0    1
```

Теперь мне необходимо пройтись по всем столбцам и проверить значение каждого элемента на `None`.
Здесь и возникла проблема. Как правильно указать в условии?
Я пробывал следующими способами, но не один не дает положительного результат.

```
for i in df.columns:
    for i in df[i]:
        if(i == None):
            print(i)
#2
for i in df.columns:
    for i in df[i]:
        if(i == np.nan):
            print(i)


#3
for i in df.columns:
    for i in df[i]:
        if(i == 'nan'):
            print(i)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что необходимо указать в условии?

Comment: Вообще можно сразу найти сколько NA в каждом столбце df как-то так, если не путаю: df.isna().sum(axis=1)

Comment: @CrazyElf df.isnull().sum() - это я знаю но мне необходимо найти не кол во и именно элемент

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня получилось только так:

```
np.isnan(i)
pd.isnull(i)
pd.isna(i)
```

По факту там лежит np.nan, но впрямую сравнивать значения с np.nan нельзя, можно только тестировать специальными функциями.

Comment: можете показать это в условном конструкции,? у меня в условиях это не срабатывает

Comment: Спасибо вам! Вы мне помогли! Работает такая конструкция: if (pd.isna(i) == True):

Comment: Вообще if и так проверяет на True, так что должно и так работать: if (pd.isna(i))

Comment: @IT-KOT, достаточно просто `if pd.isna(i)` ;) И еще - метод `df.isna()` - покажет сразу для всего DF в каких ячейках NaN

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо вам огромное за помощь! Если вас на затруднит, возможно вы сможете помочь мне с моим другим вопросом) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1096039/325850 . Заранее благодарю вас!

Comment: @IT-KOT Ответил, там всё просто